# error received when convert a pandas dataframe to spark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Since no out-of-box support for reading excel files in spark, so i first read the excel file first into a pandas dataframe, then try to convert the pandas dataframe into a spark dataframe but i got below errors
(i am using spark 1.5.1)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelFile
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

pdf=pd.read_excel('/home/testdata/test.xlsx')
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pdf)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/spark-hadoop/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 406, in createDataFrame
    rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(data, schema)
  File "/opt/spark/spark-hadoop/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 337, in _createFromLocal
    data = [schema.toInternal(row) for row in data]
  File "/opt/spark/spark-hadoop/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 541, in toInternal
    return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
  File "/opt/spark/spark-hadoop/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 541, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
  File "/opt/spark/spark-hadoop/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 435, in toInternal
    return self.dataType.toInternal(obj)
  File "/opt/spark/spark-hadoop/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 191, in toInternal
    else time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))
AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'timetuple'
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post a link to your `test.xlsx`?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9n_aOz2bmxzVUc2S084dW1KR1E/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

My best guess your problem was about "incorrectly" parsing `datetime` data when you read your data with Pandas

The following code "just works":

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelFile
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

pdf = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', parse_dates=['Created on','Confirmation time'])

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=pdf).collect()

[Row(Customer=1000935702, Country='TW',  ...
```

Please note, you have one more datetime column `'Confirmation date'` which in your example consists of `NaT` and thus reads without a problem to RDD with your short sample, but should you happen to have some data there in a full dataset you'll have to take care about that column as well.

Comment: the previous error was gone, but i got a type error. wondering if i need to solve each column type specifically? thank you   >>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pdf)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/spark-hadoop/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 406, in createDataFrame
    rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(data, schema)
  File "/opt/spark/spark-hadoop/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 322, in _createFromLocal
    ...
TypeError: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>

Comment: @b4me  You may think about accepting the solution to your earlier problem and posting new one as a new question....

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly defining the schema would fix the problem. Depending on your use case, you can dynamically specify the schema as shown in the snippet below;

```
from pyspark.sql.types import  *                                      
schema = StructType([
StructField(name, 
            TimestampType() if pd.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype(col) else
            DateType() if pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype(col) else
            DoubleType() if pd.api.types.is_float_dtype(col) else StringType(), True)
for name, col in zip(df.columns, df.dtypes)])                        
sparkDf = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema)
```